# Hadoop : HDFS Cluster running out of space even though space is available

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn, hadoop2

We have 4 datanode HDFS cluster ...there is large amount of space available on each data node of about 98gb ...but when i look at the datanode information .. it's only using about 10gb and running out of space ...

[image: Data Node information]

**How can we make it use all the 98gb and not run out of space as indicated in image**

this is the disk space configuration

[image: Disk space distribution]

this is the hdfs-site.xml on name node

```
<property>
        <name>dfs.name.dir</name>
        <value>/test/hadoop/hadoopinfra/hdfs/namenode</value>
 </property>
```

this is the hdfs-site.xml under data node

```
<property>
        <name>dfs.data.dir</name>
        <value>/test/hadoop/hadoopinfra/hdfs/datanode</value>
 </property>
```

**Eventhough /test has 98GB and hdfs is configured to use it it's not using it**

Am I missing anything while doing the configuration changes? And how can we make sure 98GB is used?

Comment: Just a thought, is your replication factor set to default? I know the default is 3 but it seems like you're using 10x the amount of storage. I'm not 100% on whether the replica copies of the blocks are counted as 'actual' storage used or not...

Comment: Failing that, does the directory you've specified in the `dfs.data.dir` property actually exist? According to the Apache website... `...Directories that do not exist are ignored.`

Comment: it does exist that directory if it doesn't exist ...start-dfs.sh will faill but it's starting properly but still using old ...location which has 14gb

Comment: Posting a _potential_ solution now :)

Answer (score 0):

According to [this Hortonworks Community Portal link](https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/2308/how-to-move-or-change-the-hdfs-datanode-directorie.html), the steps to amend your Data Node directory are as follows:

> 1. Stop the cluster.
> 2. Go to the ambari HDFS configuration and edit the datanode directory configuration: Remove /hadoop/hdfs/data and /hadoop/hdfs/data1. Add `[new directory location]`.
> 3. Login into each datanode (via SSH) and copy the contents of /data and /data1 into the new directory.
> 4. Change the ownership of the new directory and everything under it to “hdfs”.
> 5. Start the cluster.

I'm assuming that you're technically already up to Step 2 since you've displayed your correctly configured core-site.xml files in the original question. Make sure you've done the other steps and that **all Hadoop services** have been stopped. From there, change the ownership to the user running Hadoop (typically hdfs but I've worked in a place where root was running the Hadoop processes) and you should be good to go :)

Comment: this is what i'm doing on name node ..stop-dfs.sh and start-dfs.sh which i believe will restart all hadoop services ...please let me know if need to do any additional steps ...using hadoop 2.7.3

Comment: Couple of things - `stop-all.sh` and `start-all.sh` are the way to go as `stop-dfs.sh` and `start-dfs.sh` will only stop the HDFS process afaik.

Secondly, have you changed the `dfs.data.dir` property through the Ambari Admin UI (assuming you have Ambari installed) or are you doing it by editing the XML file? If Ambari is installed and you are editing the XML manually then when restarted, Ambari can revert the changes by re-applying configuration from the Database instance it uses. Also, I would recommend checking the processes are stopped using the `top` command and checking the log files.